# Array bidimensional en variable

Tags: php

Me han dado un `array` bidimensional con los días festivo de ESPAÑA y tengo una función que me calcula los días laborables sin contar los fin de semanas.

Quiero que tampoco me cuente los días festivos que hay en ese `array`, he puesto dos día de prueba solamente.

Mi problema es que no me funciona muy bien la función cuando meto los días del `array`. He probado a mostrarlos y si funciona pero no se como puedo recorrer el `array` y meter los datos en una variable.

Aquí esta el código:

```
function diashabiles($fechainicio, $fechafin){
$inicio = new DateTime($fechainicio);
$final = new DateTime($fechafin);
// Meter fecha final en la operación.
$final->modify('+1 day');

$intervalo = $final->diff($inicio);

//Días totales
$dias = $intervalo->days;

// Creamos un perido para que imprima los días (P1D es igual a 1 dia)
$periodo = new DatePeriod($inicio, new DateInterval('P1D'), $final);

//Array con días de fiesta
$holidays = array(
        array('2018-01-01'),
        array('2018-02-28'));


//echo " ".$holidays[1][0]." ";

//foreach($holidays as $di){
//  echo $di[0][0];
//}

foreach($periodo as $d) {
    $pos = $d->format('D');

    if ($pos == 'Sat' || $pos == 'Sun') {
        $dias--;
    }

    elseif (in_array($d->format('Y-m-d'), $holidays)) {
        $dias--;
    }
}

return $dias;
}
$d = diashabiles('2018-01-01 00:00:00','2018-01-01 00:00:00');
echo $d;
```

Comment: No entiendo porque tienes un array bidimensional si no hay datos asociativos en ellos, prueba asi **`$holidays = array('2018-01-01','2018-02-28');`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución simple es transformar el arreglo `$holidays` a un arreglo plano.

Para esto puedes usar [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.call-user-func-array.php) e en conjunto con [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge.php)

#### Ejemplo:

```
<?php
function diashabiles($fechainicio, $fechafin) {
    $inicio = new DateTime($fechainicio);
    $final = new DateTime($fechafin);
    // Meter fecha final en la operación.
    $final-> modify('+1 day');

    $intervalo = $final->diff($inicio);

    //Días totales
    $dias = $intervalo->days;

    // Creamos un perido para que imprima los días (P1D es igual a 1 dia)
    $periodo = new DatePeriod($inicio, new DateInterval('P1D'), $final);

    //Array con días de fiesta
    $holidays = array(
        array('2018-01-01'),
        array('2018-02-28'),
    );
    // AQUI Convertimos el arreglo de bidimensional a plano
    $holidays = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $holidays);

    foreach($periodo as $d) {
        $pos = $d->format('D');

        if ($pos == 'Sat' || $pos == 'Sun') {
            $dias--;
        } else if (in_array($d->format('Y-m-d'), $holidays)) {
            $dias--;
        }
    }

    return $dias;
}

$d = diashabiles('2018-01-01 00:00:00', '2018-01-01 00:00:00');
echo $d;
?>
```

<kbd>[`Demo`](http://rextester.com/EEBY14552)</kbd>

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!! Me sirvió de gran ayuda!